# Android Studio material library causes cannot convert String to Boolean crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-components-android

I've just bumped the material library in one of my apps to the latest (1.6.1) from 1.4.0.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

With 1.4.0 everything worked fine, but now my app crashes on launch with the following error:

```
2022-07-05 17:13:17.784 17333-17333/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nooriginalthought.amalfi, PID: 17333
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nooriginalthought.amalfi/com.nooriginalthought.amalfi.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:261)
        at o4.w.u()
        at com.nooriginalthought.amalfi.MainActivity.onCreate(:2)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
2022-07-05 17:13:26.944 1609-1623/system_process E/WindowManager: Starting window AppWindowToken{ad48a468 token=Token{ad419be0 ActivityRecord{ad079590 u0 com.nooriginalthought.amalfi/.MainActivity t84}}} timed out
```

If I comment out the following line in my onCreate() the app opens fine (though the Google Play check is not being run, which I need it to be).

```
    isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

My `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` method is defined as follows, which to me looks like it is defintely returning a boolean, so I can't see why I am getting the crash (or why a material library change would suddenly cause this, unless the error dialog is being called and failing? Even though Google Play Services IS installed on both devices I have tested on.)

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
            googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, status, GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_API_REQUEST_CODE).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am confused... I've tried resyncing Gradle and clean builds but get the same error...

-- Update --
At code-aprentice's request I am incuding the whole of `onCreate()`, though I can't see anything in there that could be triggering this specific error.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);

    isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    addExtraSslProtocolsIfNeeded();

    amalfi = Amalfi.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    affiliateRegions = new AffiliateRegions(this);


    // Read prefs and aff_ids here because they are used in start activity decision making
    amalfi.read_prefs();
    CommonFuncs.setLocale(this,amalfi.UIlang);

    // Go directly to the First Run Welcome Activity if it hasn't been shown AND acknowledged
    if (!amalfi.compWarnShown_firstRun) {
        showFirstRunMessage();
    }

    amalfi.get_affids_fromprefs(affiliateRegions);

    // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            incomingString = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
        if (intent.getDataString() != null) {
            incomingString = intent.getDataString();
        }
    }

    if ( amalfi.launchIntoBrowser && (incomingString == null || "".equals(incomingString) ) ) {
        startBrowseAmazonActivity();
    }


    // If not starting another activity, then continue loading this one as normal.
    viewBinding = MainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = viewBinding.getRoot();
    drawerViewBinding = viewBinding.drawerMenu;
    setContentView(view);

    // This if block is trying to get the auto layout transitions working - but doesn't seem to make any difference.
    viewBinding.mainLayout.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    drawerViewBinding.drawerRoot.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

    // Hide the expanded source URL block
    viewBinding.expandedSrcUrlContainer.setVisibility(GONE);

    amalfi.isPro();
    enable_and_disable_buttons();

    // Setup the in app purchases stuff
    setupBillingClient();

}
```

The only things in there that are being assigned to `String`s are from `intent.getAction()` and `intent.getType()` both of which return `Strings` according to the docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)

Comment: Look through the stack trace to find a class and method name that you wrote. I think it is `at com.nooriginalthought.amalfi.MainActivity.onCreate(:2)`. This is where you can start debugging to find what the problem is.

Comment: The Stack trace points to onCreate. It doesn't give any more detail than that. Commenting out the call to `isGooglePlayServicesAvailabke` allows the app to run without crashing so this appears to be the bad method call - even though the stack trace does not specifically identify this. But that method only returns booleans, so why a crash complaining about casting a string to a Boolean.... I don't get it, and the stack trace doesn't seem to be giving me any more clues.

Comment: I don't think the boolean return type has anything to do with the error. I'm sure you know that `boolean` is different than `Boolean`.  Also, the error is complaining about a cast from `String` to `Boolean`.

Comment: With that said, please show the `onCreate()` method. Maybe there are some hints there about what is going wrong.

Comment: Not sure the whole onCreate() will really help, but I've added it.

Comment: I'm not, either, but it won't hurt. Maybe you should try to recreate the error by creating a new Android Studio project. Then put the code you think causes the issue and see what happens.

Comment: Did you see the comment that commenting out the isGooglePLayServicesAvailable() method call results in the app running without the crash?

Comment: Yes, and you mentioned it in the original version of your question. Now that you showed where you called it from, it makes a bit more sense, but still unclear how it relates to the error.

Comment: My next suggestion is to put a breakpoint in `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` to see if you can determine where the error happens. I would start by stepping over each line in that method with F8.